# How do I keep the users selected option showing on the screen after a page refresh or reload?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have made a select drop down with 3 options.  Currently, when the user picks one of the options then refreshes the page, his selection disappears.  I need the user to be able to refresh the page and still see the option he chose before the page refresh.  Is there an AngularJS directive that does this?  If not, how can I keep the users selection from disappearing after a refresh?  There are no questions on stack overflow that address this specific issue.

Here is the html with the select tag:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="findTheBug">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./app.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="bugCTRL">

<p>5+5={{4+6}} (this is a check to make sure angular is working)</p>
<p>Choices: {{greetings}} (this is a check to make sure greetings is connected)</p>

<hr>
<select class="" name="">
  <option value="one">Stack Overflow, You're the Best!</option>
  <option value="two" ng-repeat="greeting in greetings">{{greeting}}</option>
</select>
<hr>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the angular controller in the app.js file:

```
angular
  .module("findTheBug", [])
  .controller("bugCTRL", bugCTRL);

  function bugCTRL($scope){
  $scope.greetings = ["good morning", "good evening", "good night"];
}
```

I have not been able to find an angular directive that addresses this issue, but here is an example of a select drop-down that doesn't hide the users option on a page refresh.  A working example of a sort, posted below for reference purposes only...

```
<select  class="form-control from-to-controls" ng-model="pair.from._id"  ng-change="selectEndpoint(pair.from,'{{pair.from._id}}')" ng-disabled="autoTest && testRunning || disableAll">
    <option value="NEW">New</option>
    <option ng-repeat="endpoint in endpoints" value="{{endpoint._id}}" ng-selected="endpoint.name==pair.from.name">{{endpoint.name}}</option>
</select>


<select class="form-control from-to-controls" ng-model="pair.to._id"   ng-change="selectEndpoint(pair.to,'{{pair.to._id}}')" ng-disabled="autoTest && testRunning || disableAll">
    <option value="NEW">New</option>
    <option ng-repeat="endpoint in endpoints" value="{{endpoint._id}}" ng-selected="endpoint.name==pair.to.name">{{endpoint.name}}</option>
</select>
```

I have googled, and tried adding ng-change, ng-selected, and ng-disabled to my code to attempt to replicate this code snippet above, but have not been successful.  I don't believe one of these 3 directives is related to the refresh issue I'm having, but I could be wrong.

(I spent a considerable amount of time asking this question the correct way according to stack overflow.)

Comment: COOKIES!!!!!!!!! So, make a cookie to store the user selection. Then call the cookie on `<body onload="cookieFn()">`. Simple!

Comment: You can either use cookies as mentioned or local storage, which in my opinion is the better solution because these values are not sent to the server with every request. This is supported on every major browser. Documentation and examples can be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API

Comment: Why you need to reload the webpage? Angular is a SPA so reload is not necessary. But if you must, i recommend you use Localstorage.

Comment: I am working on a project and my bosses said the users may reload the page and still need to see their selected option.  I tried to recreate the situation in this little project.  I believe they want the code to look similar to the working example above and was wondering if any angular directives can accomplish this, otherwise I will look into cookies and local storage.

Comment: @AraYaghsizian did you checked my answer ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use HTML5 [localStroage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) to store the previously selected data.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/29525/)**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.greetings = ["good morning", "good evening", "good night"];
    var selectedVal = localStorage.getItem('greeting');
    if(selectedVal) {
      $scope.greet = selectedVal;  
    }
    $scope.selectedOption = function(greet) {
      localStorage.setItem('greeting', greet);
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<select name="selectData" ng-model="greet" ng-change="selectedOption(greet)">
  <option ng-selected="true" value="">Stack Overflow, You're the Best!</option>
  <option ng-repeat="greeting in greetings">{{greeting}}</option>
</select>
</div>
```